# Putting an ArrayList into a JList using ArrayList#toArray method

Tags: java, swing, list, arraylist, jlist

I'm having trouble using the `toArray` method of the `ArrayList` class. I need to put the content of an `ArrayList`, `vecPersonnages`, into a `JList`, `listeObjets`, and I'd like to do it using `ArrayList#toArray` method. I managed to make it work by putting the values of my list in a tab and then putting this tab in the `JList`.

I did check on Google for help but everything that i found turned out not to work. I do have a `toString` method in my classes, however, i do not have a `toString` method in the class in which I utilize my `JList`.

This is how i declared my classes:

```
private JList<Personnage> listeObjets = null;
private ArrayList<Personnage> vecPersonnages = null;
```

Below is the code where I try to add the content of my `ArrayList` to the `JList` along with some things I tried, noted in comments:

```
Personnage[] tabPerso = new Personnage[vecPersonnages.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < vecPersonnages.size(); i++) {
    tabPerso[i] = vecPersonnages.get(i);
}
listeObjets.setListData(tabPerso);
//listeObjets.setListData(vecPersonnages.toArray());
//listeObjets.setListData((Personnage[]) vecPersonnages.toArray());
/*the last line gives me a ClassCastException (java.lang.Object 
  cannot be cast to personnage.Personnage)*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overloaded method of [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()), [`toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T%5B%5D));

```
Personnage[] array = new Personnage[vecPersonnages.size()]; //Create a new array with the size of the ArrayList
vecPersonnages.toArray(array); // fill the array
listeObjets.setListData(array);
```

Comment: @user2249860 You are welcome. If this answers your question, check the right mark to make this answer as the right one.